# Turning your jQuery code into a Backbone.js structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm quite a noob to Backbone.js, but I love jQuery. However I love how Backbone organizes the code into models, views and collections but I still can't get my head around how I would use it when writing JS code.

For example take this simple code I wrote in jQuery that appends a suggestions box when a user types in an input box:

```
// this is the model
var questions = [
    {question: "what is your name"},
    {question: "How old are you"},
    {question: "what is your mothers name"},
    {question: "where do work/or study"}
];

// search data function
function searchData(datas,term){
    return _.filter(datas, function(obj) {
        return ~obj.question.toLowerCase().indexOf(term);
    });
}

// Events
$("#suggestinput").on({
    keyup: function(){
        var results = searchData(questions, this.value);
        $("#suggestions")
            .addClass("active")
            .html(_.reduce(results, function(last, q){
                return last + "<p>" + q.question + "</p>";
             }, ""));
    },
    blur: function () {
        $("#suggestions").removeClass('active');
        $("#suggestions").html(" ");
    },
    focus: function () {
        if ( $(this).val() === "" ) {
            $("#suggestions").addClass('active');
            $("#suggestions").html("<p> start typing a question </p>");
        }
    }
});
```

Any advice on constructing a mini feature like this using the Backbone.js structure? I'm not saying to write the whole code, just a rough guideline or an explanation would be much appreciated.

There's also a working example of this code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X8geT/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: as any solution in Backbone, there are multiple ways to deal with a given problem, the following answer is probably completely overkill and should be taken with all due circumspection.

### Define your models

They will represent your data and how it should be handled. Here I will define a Question model (empty, but you never know), a Questions collection (where filtering for a term is defined), and a search state controller responsible for storing the current term and the matching questions:

```
var Question = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Questions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Question,
    matches: function (term) {
        if (term==="")
            return [];

        term = term.toLowerCase();
        return this.filter(function(model) {
            return model.get('question').toLowerCase().indexOf(term)!==-1
        });
    }
});

var QuestionController = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        term: ""
    },
    initialize: function(opts) {
        this.questions = opts.questions; //known questions
        this.matches = new Questions();  //filtered questions

        //when the term changes, update the matches
        this.on('change:term', function (model, term) {
            this.matches.reset(this.questions.matches(term));
        }, this);
    }
});
```

### Define your views

They will display the state of the models in the DOM and will handle interactions with the user. Let's have a SearchView that will handle the input and a SuggestionsView that will display the current suggestions:

```
var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'keyup ': function (e) {
            this.model.set('term', this.$el.val());
        },
        'focus ': function (e) {
            this.trigger('start');
        },
        'blur ': function (e) {
            this.trigger('stop');
        }
    }
});

var SuggestionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'activate', 'deactivate', 'render');
        this.listenTo(this.model.matches, 'reset', this.render);
    },
    activate: function () {
        this.$el.addClass('active');
        this.render();
    },
    deactivate: function () {
        this.$el.removeClass('active');
        this.$el.html(" ");
    },
    render: function () {
        var html = '';

        if (this.model.get("term") === "") {
            html = "<p> start typing a question </p>";
        } else {
            if (this.model.matches.length === 0) {
                html = "<p> No match </p>";
            } else {
                this.model.matches.each(function(model) {
                    html += '<p>'+model.get('question')+'</p>';            
                });
            }
        }        
        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});
```

### Bring models and views together

Instantiate, bind events and run things

```
var questions = new Questions([
    {question: "what is your name"},
    {question: "How old are you"},
    {question: "what is your mothers name"},
    {question: "where do work/or study"}
]);
var controller = new QuestionController({
    questions: questions
});

var vSearch = new SearchView({
    el: '#suggestinput',
    model: controller
});
var vSuggestions=new SuggestionsView({
    el: '#suggestions',
    model: controller
});

vSuggestions.listenTo(vSearch, 'start', vSuggestions.activate);
vSuggestions.listenTo(vSearch, 'stop', vSuggestions.deactivate);
```

And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/QSE95/

Of course, you could greatly simplify this by having a single view handling all interactions, but where would be the fun?