# How to start in BackboneJS, if I have a jQuery background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How can I start in [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org), if I have a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) background?

If I am familiar with developing client-side applications in jQuery, but now I want to start with BackboneJS. So can you describe the pattern or model(paradigm) which is necessary ?

Below are some questions that might help you make an answer:

- How can I architect and design client-side web applications in terms of JS?
- What are the Do's & Dont's?
- Is there any server side restrictions for which I have to pay more attention?

I am not seeking for a detailed comparison between jQuery and BackboneJS. I just want to start with Backbone and want to build and think any application in terms of architectural design.

Comment: That's a very broad question, probably better answered by one of the numerous tutorials out in the wild, but here's a jQuery to Backbone conversion that might give you some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967378/turning-your-jquery-code-into-a-backbone-js-structure/11968674#11968674

Comment: Here's a hall pass to two free days of code school ... I like their backboneJS intro: https://www.codeschool.com/hall_passes/213f3fedb6b9/claim_shared

Comment: "How can I architect and design client-side web applications in terms of JS?" just like in any other language, you don't need a paradigm shift, you need to learn the paradigm to begin with - you need to sit down and learn about all the patterns that UI architectures use. For example, Backbone gives you a (bad) event emitter, a (bad) mediator, and a (bad) observer. Learn about those patterns. It also utilizes the strategy pattern for routing, learn about that. When you're done with learning about those, go read a more serious design book, preferably not for JS exclusively.

Comment: My best advice about BackboneJS : Don't start with BackboneJS. Instead focus on understanding the real problems you need to solve when structuring UI. Here is a good introductory read up - http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html .

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I find most useful for up and running with backbone.js: [Lynda.com Up and running with Backbone.js with Joseph LeBlanc](http://www.lynda.com/Backbonejs-tutorials/Up-Running-Backbonejs/120900-2.html)

I think this is the best way to get started with backbone.js for one who has previous experience in Javascript/jQuery. The duration of the course is 1h33m. And here are the contents:

> Backbone helps you separate DOM manipulation from the data powering
>   your web    application. In this course, learn how to use Backbone
>   models and collections to manage your data, while displaying it
>   through views. Author Joseph LeBlanc shows you how to use events to
>   change an application's state and avoid messy nested callback
>   functions. He explores modifying resources on the server side via
>   models that reflect the changes in your application, tune your
>   application's performance, and keep the JavaScript environment clear
>   of excessive global variables. He also covers supplementary tools
>   based on Backbone that provide additional functionality.

Topics include:

- What is Backbone.js?
- Starting a node server
- Building routes
- Creating views
- Reusing views and building view templates
- Defining models
- Loading remote data
- Organizing collections
- Adding and removing models
- Saving and deleting data
- Bootstrapping data
- Finding Backbone resources